# Are cross-platform PNG-in-OTF fonts possible efficiently?

Tags: png, cross-platform, emoji, chunks, opentype

The most recent version of the [Opentype font format](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/) (1.8 as of late 2016) standardizes two different tables to embed PNG bitmap data: Google’s [`CBDT`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cbdt.htm) (together with `CBLC`) and Apple’s [`sbix`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/sbix.htm). Furthermore, the SVGs in Mozilla’s [`SVG`  table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/svg.htm) can also embed or reference PNGs.

Is it possible to embed the PNG chunks once and use them in at least two tables to make cross-platform emoji font files that are not bigger than necessary?

Side question: can PNG chunks be reused for multiple glyphs, e.g. indexed color palettes?

PS: I know that Apple’s operating systems override emojis with those from a font which has the PS name `AppleColorEmoji`.

Comment: ".. standardizes two different tables" made me smile. (Wrily, but still.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't share images across tables, e.g. use PNG images in the `sbix` table in the `cbdt` table. But if you use the exact same image files they might be "deduped" in a compressed WOFF.

Weird thing is that the CBDT/CBLC spec says a `glyf` table shouldn't be present, while the other formats require it. So you can't put `cbdt` alongside an `sbix` or `svg` table in a font. But you could combine the latter two to get relatively good support on Windows and OSX.

Comment: I can confirm that you can put both sbix and svg tables in one font :)
By the way, maybe WOFF2 would be better than WOFF in that case?

Comment: Actually I think this is wrong, I have no POC yet but I think I figured out a way to have CBLC and sbix point to the same PNG data (note _only_ PNG, will not work for sbix JPEG/TIFF): https://twitter.com/fr_brennan/status/1478240370412638211